Trouble Connecting Instagram to Facebook Page
I'm having issues connecting my Instagram to my Facebook page. I keep getting the error:
"Before connecting, you’ll need to resolve this issue."
I’ve checked everything:
I'm an admin on the page.
My Instagram is a business account.
There are no restrictions on either account.
Both apps are updated and I've tried the Facebook Business Suite but no luck. Any solutions? Thanks!
screenshot of error
I tried connecting Instagram to my Facebook page through the Facebook app, Business Suite, and Instagram settings. I expected the accounts to link without issues, but instead, I received an error saying I need to resolve something before connecting, even though no issues were found on either account.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not an actual programing question.
